# Qwest 2700 HG-D Maximum User Limit?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip-address, imac, wifi-configuration

I have a Qwest 2700 HG-D modem (w/ Wi-Fi) that I am using for home networking. Here's my problem: I have recently been trying to add another client to the Wi-Fi of the router/modem (I'm adding an AirPort Express). *When I add this device, my iMac gets 'bumped' off the wireless* - I get that I don't have an IP address. When I remove it, I can add the Mac again.

**I would like to know if the 2700 HG-D has a maximum user limit** that I might be pushing. I am considering buying another Airport Express to hook into the ethernet of the modem and turn off the modem/router's wireless completely. The users in this house are almost all Apple - iPhones, MacBooks, iPads and the like.

If anyone could direct me to a manual or something similar that would tell me this, thanks!

Erway Software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO** the modem itself does not have a maximum user limit that you have reached... based on what you have listed.  The router firmware within this model is capable of handling DHCP requests for up to 254 devices total.

[This is your modem](http://qwest.centurylink.com/internethelp/modem-270X.html), correct?

This does not automatically mean that it should be working the way you expect.

The problem here is in the settings.  First... have you contacted your ISP (since they provided you with the modem and the contract you are currently using to connect) and asked *them* how many devices you are allowed to connect to the modem?  You might be surprised with their answer.  You might be surprised to find that they actually *have* a contractual limit on the number of devices... or at the very least that there is a default setting that only passes out 10 internal IP addresses.

Now... if you don't want to contact your ISP (which is what I would have done before posting a question here, but that's just me), you *can* go out, purchase a third party wireless router, and follow the [instructions here to set up your modem as a transparent bridge](http://c.search.centurylink.com/internethelp/modems/2wire2700HG/pdf/2700HG_D_Configuration___Transparent_Bridging.pdf).  Why would you want to do such a thing?  Well, for one, you are only monkeying around with a minimum number of settings.  For another, you shouldn't have to contact your ISP.

It is possible to expand the DHCP range for your Qwest modem.  Doing so might just violate your TOS with your provider.

Comment: Check your DHCP settings first, its easy and calling customer service can be horrific.

Comment: Yep, that's my model

Comment: @RyanE What should my DHCP settings look like?

Comment: I would have my DHCP look like this: 192.168.0.20-.254  That would leave you some space in the bottom of your network for static devices and allow for plenty of connections in the open range.